# Datepicker reload issue

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Using the datepicker plugin I am receiving the following error

> TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function     at
>   HTMLDocument.eval (eval at 
>   (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:2538),
>   :6:31)     at m.Callbacks.j (eval at 
>   (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:2538),
>   :2:27295)     at Object.m.Callbacks.k.add [as done] (eval
>   at

Comment: Could you please include the code you've tried in order to get this error

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/1/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/1/daterangepicker-bs3.css" />
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
```

Please make sure that you have included the right script files, in a correct order :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="daterangepicker-bs3.css" />
```

You can download these scripts here:
    http://www.jsdelivr.com/

Comment: yes i have been using the same .even though i am getting this issue..can anyone please help me out..

Comment: @Venigalla please show us your code, edit your question

Comment: @Venigalla I created a snippet for you, change your code accordingly

Comment: angular.min.js,angular-route.min.js,angular-cookies.js,d3.v3.min.js,d3.min.js,jquery.js,bootstrap.js,moment.js,daterangepicker.js these are the js files i am using .if i place my angular js files first and then date picker files ..datepicker functionaliy does not works.And then vice versa i am getting fallowing error like.. $(...).daterangepicker is not a function at HTMLDocument.eval .please help me out

Comment: @Venigalla please add your code to your question so that i can check where you made a mistake, click the 'edit' link under your question to edit